# Открытие сайта в браузере с помощью Python (3.10.4) на MacBook Air M1

Tags: python, браузер, mac, anaconda

Использую ноутбук MacBook Air (M1). Пробую делать открытие страницы в браузере через IDLE Shell, все застопорилось.

Если ввести адрес сайта (с https://), то if в IDLE Shell всплывает, но ни один из браузеров не подает признаков жизни. Как я понимаю, нужен какой-то костыль, чтобы система откликнулась? Гуглежка говорит, что нужен Anaconda-Navigator, я его поставил, но что с ним делать - ума не приложу.

```
import os

sayt = input ()

if 'https://' in sayt:
    os.system('start ' + sayt)
    print ('if')
```

Answer (score 0):

`start` - это команда специфическая для Windows. Для открытия ссылки в браузере вместо `os.system` используйте стандартный модуль [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html), пример:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open("https://example.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

sayt = input ()

if 'https://' in sayt:

    os.system('start ' + sayt)
    print ('if')
```

внимательно к пробелам, я именно так нашел ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже на М1 учусь. Я так понимаю, что ты выполняешь из 7-часового видео задание.

```
import webbrowser
sayt = input()
if 'https://' in sayt:
    webbrowser.open(sayt)
    print('if')

elif 'www.' in sayt:
    sayt = 'https://' + sayt
    webbrowser.open(sayt)
    print('elif')

else:
    sayt = 'https://www.' + sayt
    webbrowser.open(sayt)
    print('else')
```

Comment: а это точно ответ на вопрос? если да, то добавьте, пожалуйста, объяснение, нажав [edit]